# A question on Green's functions & integral operators

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I'm fairly new to the concept of Green's functions, but from what I understand so far, they are a powerful tool for solving PDEs with boundary conditions.

Given a differential equation (in operator form)
$$\mathcal{L}u(x)=f(x)$$ (where $\mathcal{L}$ is a differential operator) it is possible to find a solution for $u(x)$ of the form
$$u(x)=\int G(x,\xi)f(\xi)d\xi$$
I'm struggling to understand the motivations given for the integral operator form of the solution given above. Why is it possible to represent it like this?

I understand that the motivation partially comes from the fact that $\mathcal{L}$ will have an inverse (assuming that $\mathcal{L}$ is *non-singular*), and as it is a differential operator this implies that the inverse $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ will be an *integral operator*. From the differential equation above we have $$u(x)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}f(x)$$ What is the motivation for introducing a so-called *Green's function* $G(x,\xi)$ such that the integral operator is of the form given above? Is it just that $G(x,\xi)$ is a generator of the operator?

Also, is the reason why we end up with the defining equation for a Green's function $$\mathcal{L}G(x,\xi)=\delta (x-\xi)$$ simply because $\mathcal{L}\cdot\mathcal{L}^{-1}=\mathbf{1}$ and the fact that we can *formally* write (as $\mathcal{L}$ is *linear*) $$\mathcal{L}u(x)=\mathcal{L}\left(\int G(x,\xi)f(\xi)d\xi\right)=\int \left(\mathcal{L}G(x,\xi)\right)f(\xi)d\xi=f(x)\quad\Rightarrow\quad\mathcal{L}G(x,\xi)=\delta (x-\xi)$$

Comment: are you familiar with delta function and fourier transform?

Comment: @grdgfgr       yes, I am.

Comment: What you are doing is you are reconstructing $f(x)$ in terms other functions. For this method the delta function is the easiest one. It is trivial to reconstruct a function with delta functions, you simply convolve itself with the delta function. If you could write $f(x)=n(x) \star n(x)$ then you could solve $LK(x,\xi)=n(x-\xi)$ and then do $K\star m$

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It is well known that some differential equations can be solved by integration, for example $f'(x)=g(x)$, $g(0)=g_0$. It is natural to try to solve more complicated equations this way and Green's function was invented for that. It turns out this can be done on many cases. Also for specific equations it can have concrete interpretation. In electrostatics Green's function $G(x,y)$ of Laplace equation is electric point at point $x$ created by unit charge at point $y$.

Comment: @Blazej        I guess intuition as to what a Green's function actually is and what motivates us to construct an integral operator in terms of it?

Comment: @Blazej laplace's equation is homogeneous. it is usually called poisson's equation if it is inhomogeneous.

Comment: @grdgfgr       So is any of what I put in my original question correct?

Comment: This is a fantastic question, answer and use of the MSE. Bravo. That said, you might also get something from my much less enlightened calculations at: http://www.supermath.info/TransferFunctions.pdf where I derived the integral kernel from other methods for a few standard examples and connect with some of the engineering jargon about transfer functions. Understanding Green's function better is something that's been on my to-do list for a while...

Comment: @JamesS.Cook  Thanks! And thanks for the link to your notes, they look pretty comprehensive. Yes, it's something that I've been trying to get my head round for a while also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword here is *linearity*. A physicist would say that you are employing the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). You are decomposing your source term $f$ into a superposition of localized impulses: 
$$
f(x)=\int_\Omega f(y)\delta(x-y)\, dy.$$
Since the equation is linear, to solve 
$$
L_x u (x)=f(x)=\int_\Omega f(y)\delta(x-y)\, dy$$
you can solve the family of equations
$$
L_x G_y(x)=\delta(x-y), \qquad y\in \Omega$$
then multiply by $f(y)$ and superpose back:
$$\tag{1}
u(x)=\int_\Omega f(y)G_y(x)\,dy.$$
By linearity, you expect $(1)$ to be a solution to your original problem. (And of course people usually write $G(x, y)$ instead of $G_y(x)$).

To understand better, try looking in an electromagnetism book and see how it solves the equation 
$$
-\Delta \phi = \frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon_0},$$
where $\phi$ is the electrostatic potential and $\rho$ is the density of charge (and $\epsilon_0$ is the dielectric constant of the vacuum - I hope I have put the right constant). This is the prototypical example of Green's function.

Comment: So is the point that the source term can be reconstructed from integrating  its value at each point over a given interval (by superposing its value at each point)?  Is any of what I put in my original post correct as a motivation? Can we just view the Green's function as defining the action of the integral operator on a given function at each point (is this what is meant when people refer to a Green's function as the *kernel* of an integral operator?)

Comment: The first two questions really do not need an answer, as you already got them. For the third, I think that "kernel" is just a jargon to designate the function one integrates against in an integral operator. There is no particularly deep meaning, IMHO. (And I agree that "kernel" is one of the most abused words in mathematics). You can see it as a continuum version of the concept of matrix: a matrix $A$ acts as follows $$Ax(i)=\sum_j a(i, j)x(j)$$ while a linear integral operator $I$ acts as follows: $$If(x)=\int G(x, y)f(y)\, dy.$$

Comment: Ah, so could one think of $G(x,y)$ as the components (in the continuum limit) of the integral operator? If this is the case, then it makes sense to me that once one has deduced that the inverse of the operator $\mathcal{L}$ should be an integral operator, that it should have that particular form.

Comment: You can think like that. But don't get too excited. Note that, formally, *anything* linear can be written as an integral operator: $$L_xu(x)=L_x\int u(y)\delta(x-y)\, dy =\int L_x(\delta(x-y))u(y)\, dy=\int H(x, y)u(y)\, dy.$$

Comment: (If I remember correctly, something like that is written in Dirac's book on quantum mechanics, where he introduced the [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)). The problem with this approach is that $H$ needs not be a function at all. (If $L$ is a differential operator, that's never going to be the case). If that's the case, then the previous representation is useless.

Comment: I think it's starting to become a little clearer. I'll have to take at look at Dirac's book.